# how to combine two images on one window matlab?

Tags: matlab

i have two images of size lets say image1=250x250 and image2=250x550.
i want to have an image that shows these two images combine.
like image3=image1+image2 means image3=250x800.

Answer (score 12):

Combining the images can be done easily using [concatenation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-84864.html#f1-85019):

```
image3 = [image1 image2];  %# Concatenate horizontally
```

And you can then visualize `image3` using any of the functions [IMAGE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/image.html), [IMAGESC](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imagesc.html), or [IMSHOW](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imshow.html):

```
image(image3);  %# Display the image in a figure window
```

**NOTE:**

You didn't mention what type of images you are dealing with, only that they are 2-dimensional matrices of pixel data. This means they could be [binary images](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/f14-13543.html#f14-33397) (with pixel values of 0 or 1), [grayscale images](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/f14-13543.html#f14-13941) (with pixel values that represent a range from black to white), or [indexed color images](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/f14-13543.html#f14-17587) (with pixel values that represent indices into a colormap).

For binary and grayscale images, the above solution should work fine. However, indexed color images could be trickier to combine if each image has its own unique [colormap](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/colormap.html). If the image is loaded from a file using the function [IMREAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imread.html), you can get the color map like so:

```
[image1,map1] = imread('image1.png');  %# Image and colormap for image file 1
[image2,map2] = imread('image2.png');  %# Image and colormap for image file 2
```

Now, if `map1` and `map2` contain different arrangements of colors, the two images can't be so easily combined. One solution would be to first convert the images to 3-dimensional [truecolor images](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/f14-13543.html#f14-20224) using the function [IND2RGB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ind2rgb.html), then combine them using the function [CAT](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/techdoc/ref/cat.html):

```
image1 = ind2rgb(image1,map1);  %# Convert image 1 to RGB
image2 = ind2rgb(image2,map2);  %# Convert image 2 to RGB
image3 = cat(2,image1,image2);  %# Concatenate the images along dimension 2
```

And now you can view `image3` as described above.

Comment: CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent............"why do i get this error while concatenation"

Comment: @chee: It means either your images don't have the same number of rows or you are potentially trying to concatenate a 2-D image with a 3-D one.

Comment: bt wt if i want to join them any way?

Comment: @chee: Then you'll have to either [resize](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imresize.html), [crop](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imcrop.html), or [pad](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/padarray.html) the images so that the mismatched dimensions are equal.

Comment: If img1 is binary and img2 is grayscale, when I concatenate and save them. The binary img is all black? How to resolve it?

Comment: @FarazAhmad: you would need to scale your logical image so it spans the same range as your grayscale image.

Comment: @gnovice How can I scale it? I have written a loop to multiply each value by 255, but it is still a matrix of zeros and ones.

Comment: @FarazAhmad: Without sample code or images to work from, I can't provide you with a definitive solution, other than to try casting the binary image to double before scaling: `img1 = double(img1);`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did img1 = unit8(img1); then multiplied each cell by 255 and got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to view the two images side by side, you can display multiple images (or graphs) in the same figure using `subplot`.