# joining images of different dimensions in matlab

Tags: matlab

if i have two images of different dimensions....than
can i do it like i have a window with size equal to the sum of sizes of two images, means
 window( size)=size of image1+size of image 2 
and than paste these mages on this window to show them jointly
.....is it possible?if yes than how

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to combine two images on one window matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037779/how-to-combine-two-images-on-one-window-matlab)

Comment: @gnovice not exactly duplicate as the sizes here are not the same.

Answer (score 2):

From your description it sounds you want to construct a block-diagonal matrix from the two images, since then the size of the result will be the sum of sizes (along each dimension). The way to do it is to use the `blkdiag` function:

```
img1 = randn(70,100);
img2 = randn(50,110);
img = blkdiag(img1,img2);
imshow(img)
```

Of course the off-diagonal blocks are padded with zeros.

EDIT:

Answering your refined question, you have to pad the shorter image with zeros so it becomes at the same height as the longer image. Then you can concatenate them side by side. Assuming `img1` is **longer**, it would look something like:

```
h1 = size(img1, 1);
[h2, w2] = size(img2);
img2a = [img2; zeros(h1-h2, w2)];
img = [img1, img2a];
```

Comment: but i want to join images horizantally.

Comment: But you said you want the size to be sum of sizes. If you join them horizontally, the result will have the height of the longer one, not the sum. Please explain in more detail what you try to achieve.

Comment: ok yes you are right....what i want is the resulting image with longer height.if dimension of image1=250x320 ,and of image2=220x320....resulting image should have dimensions =250x640.

Answer (score 2):

I have written this code to join two images horizontally. img1 and img2 should be grayscale.

```
function [ output_args ] = sideBySideImage( img1, img2 )
%UNTITLED Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here, expects a black and white images


    [r1, c1] = size(img1);
    [r2, c2] = size(img2);

    if r1<r2    %rows in first img are less, so we add some rows in it
        temp_row = zeros(1,c1);
        while r1~=r2
            img1 = [img1; temp_row];
            [r1, c1] = size(img1);
            [r2, c2] = size(img2);
        end
    elseif r1>r2    %rows in second img are less, so we add some rows in it
        temp_row = zeros(1,c2);
        while r1~=r2
            img2 = [img2; temp_row];
            [r1, c1] = size(img1);
            [r2, c2] = size(img2);
        end
    end



    output_args = [img1, img2];

end
```